# Sumarize code to loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have code

```
dict_a[box_1_a] = text_1_a;
dict_a[box_2_a] = text_2_a;
dict_a[box_3_a] = text_3_a;
dict_a[box_4_a] = text_4_a;
dict_a[box_5_a] = text_5_a;
dict_a[box_6_a] = text_6_a;
```

how to summarize the code looks like this

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
  dict_a[box_(i)_a] = text_(i)_a;
}
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If boxes and texts are class members, correct syntax should be

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
  dict_a[this["box_" + i + "_a"]] = this["text_" + i + "_a"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should first save your box_1_a and text objects in an array, so you can iterate over them via:

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    dict_a[box_a[i]] = text_a[i];
}
```

I don't know if the syntax is correct for AS/Flash, but that's how it will basically work.